# How to get the root folder name from javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-server

This question is same as [How to find the current folder through JS COM?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89676/how-to-find-the-current-folder-through-js-com) this one. But my problem is
I can't get the folder name from the root folder, For instance

Consider `final` is the root folder in share point. And `final` folder contain the several folders. I'm trying to get the folder name from the `final` folder,
I tried with the following script this is copied from the another answer

```
var currentFolder = decodeURIComponent(ctx.rootFolder).split("/").pop();
```

This is not giving the folder name from the root folder, but it is working while directory moved into the child folders.

```
  /final                #Here folder name is not giving
  /final/1/             #While moving into child folder name is giving by the above code
  /final/2/             #,,,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best way but I guess it will work.

```
decodeURIComponent(ctx.rootFolder==""?ctx.listUrlDir:ctx.rootFolder).split("/").pop();
```